# Houghpeaks Equavilent in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, hough-transform

I'm trying to use function **houghpeaks** in octave

```
I = rgb2gray(img);
BW = edge(I,'canny');
[H,T,R] = hough(BW); 
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
```

but i get Error :

warning: the 'houghpeaks' function belongs to the image package from Octave Forge
but has not yet been implemented.

> is there any Equivalent to houghpeaks in octave and how to use it?

Comment: If this is for personal use, in theory if you have access to matlab and grab the `houghpeaks.m` from it, it will work on octave (you'll have to load the image package first). If it's not for personal use, be warned that there may be licensing / ethical issues at play and you'd be better off writing your own function. (and if you do, feel free to contribute it to the octave project).

Comment: PS. I have tested the matlab function in octave and it works as expected. The 'example' given had to be tweaked slightly because the call to imrotate was broken and needed the 'method' parameter passed explicitly, i.e. `imrotate(I, 50, 'nearest', 'crop')`, but otherwise no change was needed to the houghpeaks function itself.